# Stanford Javascript Crypto Library Decryption

Tags: javascript

This function works fine to encrypt but when I call the decrypt function I am not getting anything out to the console, before I was getting an error saying it was not a JSON object, so I called JSON.parse on it and for some reason that worked. The encryption is working as I expect.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/src/core_random.js.html"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="sjcl/sjcl.js"></script>

  <script> 
    function StanfordCrypto(){
      this.encrypt = function(){
      sjcl.random = new sjcl.prng(8);
      sjcl.random.startCollectors();
      document.body.onmousemove = function() {
        console.log(sjcl.random.getProgress(8));
        if(sjcl.random.isReady(8) === 2) {
          document.body.onmousemove = "";
          sjcl.random.stopCollectors();
          this.keyArray = sjcl.random.randomWords(5,8);
          for(i=0;i<this.keyArray.length;i++){
            this.key += this.keyArray[i];
          }
          this.encryptedData = sjcl.encrypt(this.key+"dlksdhaslkhdewrhewuiryewio","Test");
          document.getElementById("crypto").innerHTML += this.encryptedData;
        }
      };
    };
    this.decrypt = function(){
      decryptedData = sjcl.decrypt(this.key+"dlksdhaslkhdewrhewuiryewio",this.encryptedData);
      alert(decryptedData);
      document.getElementById("crypto").innerHTML += "<br/>" + decryptedData;
    };
}
  function initiate(){
    encryption = new StanfordCrypto();
    encryption.encrypt();
    encryption.decrypt();
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="initiate();"><h1>It works!</h1>
  <p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
  <p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
  <div style="break-word:normal;" id="crypto"></div>
</body>
```

URL: beef.nerdsville.net

Comment: I'd suggest you learn how to use `var` in front of your local variables or you will quickly have unintended bugs.

Comment: I added var to the two local variables in the script, thanks. The issue still persists though, but it is good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks fundamentally flawed to me.

Upon calling `.encrypt()` you are installing a `mousemove` event handler, but that event handler won't get called until long after the `.encrypt()` method has finished.

Then, you're actually doing the encryption in the mousemove event handler (which happens some time later).

This means you're calling `.decrypt()` before `.encrypt()` has even done it's work (e.g. before the `mousemove` event handler has ever been called and thus before the actual encryption has been done.

---

Some other points of feedback:

1. All local variables should be declared with `var` in front of them.  Otherwise, they become implicit global variables and one function's variables can easily trounce on others.
2. You have a design that is half synchronous and half asynchronous.  You need to be fully one or the other.  Either do the collector stuff when the page is initialized long before any calls to encrypt or decrypt so they can be synchronous (as they usually are) or change your encrypt/decrypt logic to be asynchronous so it can handle the asynchronous nature of your mousemove event handler.
3. Consider adding some comments to your code to document what you're trying to do.
4. Return data from functions with the `return` statement, not in global variables.
5. Separate your crypto functions from functions that put data into the DOM.  Crypto operations should be generic and should return the encrypted/decrypted data which the caller can then place into the DOM if needed.  If you want a function to do that, then make a higher level function that calls the crypto function and then does the DOM operation.